# How do I Remove Data From Non-Scaled Dataframe against a Scaled One

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm using R right now where I'm scaling the original data, removing all outliers with a Z-Score of 3 or more, and then filtering out the unscaled data so that it contains only non-outliers. I want to be left with a data frame that contains non-scaled numbers after removing outliers. These were my steps:

**Steps**

1. Create two data frames (**x, y**) of the same data

2. Scale **x** and leave **y** unscaled.

3. Filter out all rows that have greater than 3 Z-Score in **x**

4. Currently, for example, **x** may have 95,000 rows while **y** still has 100,000

5. Truncate **y** based on a unique column called **Row ID**, which I made sure was unscaled in **x**. This unique column will help me match up the remaining rows in **x** and the rows in **y**. 

6. **y** should now have the same number of rows as **x**, but with the data unscaled. **x** has the scaled data.

At the moment I can't get the data to be unscaled. I tried using the unscale method or data frame comparison tools but R complains I cannot work on data frames of two different sizes. Is there a workaround to this?

**Tries**

I've tried `dataFrame <- dataFrame[dataFrame$Row %in% remainingRows]` but that left nothing in my data frame.

I would also provide data, but it has sensitive information, so any data frame will do so long as it has a unique row ID that won't change during scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, I'm suggesting a different approach. You could use two `data.frames` for that, but if you use the `dplyr`package, you can do everything within a single line of code ... and presumably faster as well.

First I'm generating a `data.frame` with 100k rows, which has an `ID` column (just 1:100000 sequence) and a `value` (random numbers).

Here's the code:

```
library(dplyr)

#generate data
x <- data.frame(ID=1:100000,value=runif(100000,max=100)*runif(10000,max=100))

#take a look

> head(x)
  ID      value
1  1  853.67941
2  2  632.17472
3  3 3089.60716
4  4 8448.89408
5  5 5307.75684
6  6   19.07485
```

To filter out the outliers, I'm using a `dplyr` pipe, where I chain multiple operations together with the pipe (`%>%`) operator. First calculate the `zscore`, then `filter` the observations with a `zscore` bigger than three, and finally drop the `zscore` column again to go back to your original format (of course you can keep it as well):

```
xclean <- x %>% mutate(zscore=(value-mean(value)) / sd(value)) %>%
 filter(zscore < 3) %>% select(-matches('zscore'))
```

If you look at the rows, you'll see that the filtering worked

```
> cat('Rows of X:',nrow(x),'- Rows of xclean:',nrow(xclean))
Rows of X: 100000 - Rows of xclean: 99575
```

while the data looks like the original `data.frame`:

```
> head(xclean)
  ID      value
1  1  853.67941
2  2  632.17472
3  3 3089.60716
4  4 8448.89408
5  5 5307.75684
6  6   19.07485
```

Finally, you can see that observations have been filtered out by comparing the `ID`s of the two `data.frame`s:

```
> head(x$ID[!is.element(x$ID,xclean$ID)],50)
 [1]    68    90   327   467   750   957  1090  1584  1978  2106  2306  3415  3511  3801  3855  4051
[17]  4148  4244  4266  4511  4875  5262  5633  5944  5975  6116  6263  6631  6734  6773  7320  7577
[33]  7619  7731  7735  7889  8073  8141  8207  8966  9200  9369  9994 10123 10538 11046 11090 11183
[49] 11348 11371
```

---

#### EDIT:

Of course, the 2 data frames version is also possible:

```
y <- x

# calculate zscore
x$value <- (x$value - mean(x$value))/sd(x$value)

#subset y
y <- y[x$value<3,]

# initially 100k rows
> nrow(y)
[1] 99623
```

---

#### Edit2:

Accounting for multiple value columns:

```
#generate data
set.seed(21)
x <- data.frame(ID=1:100000,value1=runif(100000,max=100)*runif(10000,max=100),
                value2=runif(100000,max=100)*runif(10000,max=100),
                value3=runif(100000,max=100)*runif(10000,max=100))

    > head(x)
  ID    value1     value2      value3
1  1 2103.9228 5861.33650  713.885222
2  2  341.8342 3940.68674  578.072141
3  3 5346.2175  458.07089    1.577347
4  4  400.1950 5881.05129 3090.618355
5  5 7346.3321 4890.56501 8989.248186
6  6 5305.5105   38.93093  517.509465
```

The `dplyr` solution:

```
# make sure you got a recent version of dplyr
> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.7.2’

# define zscore function:
zscore <- function(x){(x-mean(x))/sd(x)}

# select variables (could also be manually with c())
vars_to_process <-  grep('value',colnames(x),value=T)


# calculate zscores and filter

xclean <- x %>% mutate_at(.vars=vars_to_process, .funs=funs(ZS = zscore(.))) %>%
                filter_at(vars(matches('ZS')),all_vars(.<3)) %>% 
                select(-matches('ZS'))

> nrow(xclean)
[1] 98832
```

Now the solution without `dplyr` (instead of using 2 dataframes, I'll generate a boolean index based on `x`:

```
# select variables
vars_to_process <-  grep('value',colnames(x),value=T)

# create index ZS < 3
ix <- apply(x[vars_to_process],2,function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x) < 3)

#filter rows
xclean <- x[rowSums(ix) == length(vars_to_process),]

> nrow(xclean)
[1] 98832
```

Comment: Whoah I'll have to give this a run. This looks super good! I'll get back to you once I try it out. Edit: and if I need to apply the function over multiple columns? In the example a single 'value' column is shown. How would going through X columns work (excluding RowID)?